# Black faces after baking a texture

Tags: baking

I am having trouble baking a texture from a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh. Some faces remain black.
[image: low poly mesh]
The low poly mesh is cleanly unwrapped.
There are no overlaps.
There are no flipped normals.
I tried baking with a cage and with extrusion.
Here are my settings
[image: Settings]

I have also tried with a higher number (32) of render samples.

Edit:
In the meantime I found out that some faces are simply ignored (I marked the corresponding place on the texture in red).
[image]
Very annoying and probably related to the same problem are the clearly visible seams (marked in blue). I can blur them afterwards, but I can't find a way to make the transitions smoother right away.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have since figured out that the problem was the size of the texture. In the high poly model there were 16 textures, each with 8k. With a 16K texture  in the low poly model there were no more black faces. I guess Blender ignores faces if the corresponding area on the texture is too small (less than 1 px?).

So the solution is: bake a 16K texture and reduce the texture to the desired size afterwards.